# VB.NET move nested Classes to own File

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a rather untypical situation:
When I build an Application, I created a class witch contained several nested classes. At the beginning, this was manageable, but now so the file is so big, that I want to move each nested class to its own file.
Is this possible in VB.NET, or do I need to move each nested class out of the "mother" class?
I have Resharper installed, if this helps..

Structure:

```
Public Class A
   Public Class NestedA
   End Class

   Public Class NestedB
   End Class

End Class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yfzd5350.aspx) class:

```
Partial Public Class ParcialTest

    Public Class NestedA
    End Class

End Class
```

And in another file:

```
Partial Public Class ParcialTest

    Public Class NestedB
    End Class

End Class
```

Compiler will merge all these `Partial` class parts into one for you.